# Se cambia del Display Member al Value Member en DataGridViewComboBoxColumn c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

necesito ayuda por favor, tengo un DataGridView con varios campos y uno de ellos es un ComboBoxColumn ya tiene datos, como lo verán.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora cuando seleccione el dato que deseo agregar en esa fila, se visualiza perfectamente, pero cuando salgo de la celda se cambia al valueMember y lo quiero que se quede el nombre no el Id.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien por favor me puede ayudar a como resolver este problema que tengo.
agradeceré la ayuda que me puedan prestar.

Gracias

R.M.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código en donde llenas el ComboBoxColumn?

Comment: En este instante, muchas gracias 
GrupoId.DataSource = tblGrupoComprasGasto.ListaGrupoComprasEgresos();
            GrupoId.ValueMember = "Id";
            GrupoId.DisplayMember = "NombreGrupo";

Comment: Trata indicando value y display member antes de asignar el DataSource: GrupoId.ValueMember = "Id"; GrupoId.DisplayMember = "NombreGrupo"; GrupoId.DataSource = tblGrupoComprasGasto.ListaGrupoComprasEgresos();

Comment: No. no funciono estimado. hace lo mismo selecciona bien pero al salir de la celda se cambia al valuemenber

Comment: la verdad he intentado y buscado pero casi nadie hace ejemplos de esto y si lo hacen es trayendo datos de la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar qué regresa el método tblGrupoComprasGasto.ListaGrupoComprasEgresos() ?

Comment: public static List<tblGrupoComprasGasto> ListaGrupoComprasEgresos()
        {
            using (GourmetEntities db = new GourmetEntities())
            {
                return db.tblGrupoComprasGastos.ToList();
            }
        }

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110218/discussion-between-carlos-pozos-and-roberto-carlos-melgar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre es buena práctica mapear a DTOs las entidades para evitar errores y agregar lógica como validaciones, acceso a datos, permisos como la edición, etc.

Intenta realizar lo siguiente:

```
public class ComprasGastoDTO
{   
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string NombreGrupo { get; private set; }

    public ComprasGastoDTO(int id, int nombreGrupo)
    {
        Id = id;
        NombreGrupo = nombreGrupo;
    }

    private static readonly List<ComprasGastoDTO> ComprasList = new List<ComprasGastoDTO>();

    public static List<ComprasGastoDTO> ObtenerCompras()
    {
        ComprasList.Clear();

        List<tblGrupoComprasGasto> entities = new List<tblGrupoComprasGasto>();
        using (GourmetEntities db = new GourmetEntities()) 
        { 
            entities = db.tblGrupoComprasGastos.ToList(); 
        }

        // Mapeas las entidades
        foreach(var entity in entities)
        {
            var dto = new ComprasGastoDTO(entity.Id, entity.NombreGrupo);
            ComprasList.Add(dto);
        }

        return ComprasList;
    }
}
```

```
GrupoId.ValueMember = "Id"; 
GrupoId.DisplayMember = "NombreGrupo"; 
GrupoId.DataSource = new ComprasGastoDTO().ObtenerCompras();
```